# recursive generated breadcrump from a given tree for router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I try to create a breadcrump from a given json tree in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/alaber/y1v2bosn/1/

Thats so far working and I get the full path, but how can I use this code to create a breadcrump component for my router in vuejs to navigate inside the given tree from my json?

For example that I can use the link to directly go to the path Cocker like:

```
Animals / Dogs / Cocker
```

Or did I think wrong about the router concept and how to build breadcrumbs?

Maybe its possible to build it on another way?

Like if I click on a child node, then add it to the current breadcrumb arrays as item and if I click on a child of this child add it as 2. item to the breadcrumb, like in a more static way?

thank you

Comment: I would suggest to use something that already exists, like [this](https://github.com/Scrum/vue-2-breadcrumbs) or using vue-router like [this](https://medium.com/@fagnersaraujo/automated-breadcrumbs-with-vuejs-7e1051de8028) and not trying to build anything new, as it's already been tested and patched a few times - I always prefer to focus on my own application and not ways to get there 

Comment: #thanks your right, I came up with: https://medium.com/@pratheekhegde/displaying-application-breadcrumbs-in-vue-js-85456dc8a370